# Hide a PXButton on a popup screen

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to hide a PXButton on a popup screen

[image]

Here is my code:

```
protected void _(Events.RowSelected<POReceipt> e)
{
    if (e.Row is null) return;
    ActionMoveAll.SetEnabled(e.Row.ReceiptType == POReceiptType.TransferReceipt);
    ActionMoveAll.SetVisible(e.Row.ReceiptType == POReceiptType.TransferReceipt);
}

<px:PXButton runat="server" ID="btnfillwithall" CommandName="actionMoveAll" CommandSourceID="ds" />
```

I have set AutoRepaint="true" and autoreload="true" and loadOnDemand="true" all to no luck. When the PXButton hits the server I do get a popup saying "the FillWithAll action is disabled", but I would like for it just to be removed entirely from the popup instead of just getting an error response.

Comment: how did you bind the action and the button? add the screenshot with the settings in the question

Comment: Just updated it

Comment: @KyleVanderstoep it looks like your button is associated with actionMoveAll while you are hiding FillWithAll

Comment: That was just my failure to type, they are the same name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do `ActionMoveAll.SetVisible()` in the primary DAC RowSelected event handler `_(Events.RowSelected<POReceipt> e)`. You should move `ActionMoveAll.SetVisible(e.Row.ReceiptType == POReceiptType.TransferReceipt)` to your popup window DAC RowSelected event handler. In your case it might be like `_(Events.RowSelected<POReceiptLineAllocation> e)`

Add `SyncVisible=""` to your PXButton as well. Set it to **True** (or **False** if True doesn't work, and check the result. One setting should work)